# (ajuda PHP) 4 palavras iguais

Tags: php

Entao estou fazendo um projeto com a palavra 'Cachorro' que procura no arquivo teste.. se tiver 4 'Cachorro' ele da resultado, se nao ==>(Cachorro) Não Existe ou tem menos de 3 palavra  no teste.txt
mas eu nao estou conseguindo colocar '>3" maior de 3

**estrutura do projeto**

```
<?php
    $arquivo = strtolower(file_get_contents('teste.txt'));
    $textoBuscar = strtolower('Cachorro');

    if(strpos($arquivo, $textoBuscar )!== FALSE){
        echo '<h1>mais de 3 palavras ((Cachorro)) no teste.txt< /h1>';
    } else {
        echo '<h1>(Cachorro) Não Existe ou tem menos de 1 palavra  no teste.txt< /h1>';

    }

?>
```

Comment: se a resposta resolveu seu problema, marque-a como aceita veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx7Ts.png e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079. Editei a resposta indicando uma pesquisa sem distinção entre maiúsculas e minúsculas

Answer (score 2):

> A função preg_match_all() retornará um número inteiro com a quantidade de ocorrências encontradas pela expressão regular.

```
<?php

$arquivo = file_get_contents('cachorro.txt');
$count = preg_match_all("/Cachorro/", $arquivo, $matches);

if($count>3)
{

   echo '<h1>mais de 3 palavras ((Cachorro)) no teste.txt Tem '.$count.'< /h1>';

} else {

   echo '<h1>(Cachorro) Não Existe ou tem '.$count.' no teste.txt< /h1>';

}
?>
```

[**Exemplo no ideone**](https://ideone.com/kDzRve)

> O "i" após o delimitador indica uma pesquisa sem distinção entre maiúsculas e minúsculas

```
preg_match_all("/Cachorro/i", $arquivo, $matches);
```

Comment: show vlw obrigado